# Unable to Consume Linkedin API through Localhost

Tags: javascript, api, exception, dns, linkedin-api

I found similar threads but unfortunately didn't help resolve my issue so posting a new thread

I am trying to consume the linked API through **localhost**. The error I am getting is:

> Uncaught Error: You must specify a valid JavaScript API Domain as part of this key's configuration.

Under Javascript Settings, Valid SDK Domains I added

- http://127.0.0.1
- http://127.0.0.1:8704
- http://localhost
- http://localhost:8704
- http://localhost

I tried adding in https as well but still I am facing the same error. 
I tried creating a ASP.NET project in Visual studio and tried running my html file with the associated port number which also I added in valid SDK domain, still the same issue.

My code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">  
api_key: [MY KEY] //Client ID  
onLoad: OnLinkedInFrameworkLoad //Method that will be called on page load  
authorize: true  
</script>  
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">  
function OnLinkedInFrameworkLoad() {  
    console.log('OnLinkedInFrameworkLoad');
    IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", OnLinkedInAuth);  
}  

function OnLinkedInAuth() {  
    console.log('OnLinkedInAuth');
    IN.API.Profile("me").result(ShowProfileData);  
}  

function ShowProfileData(profiles) {  
    console.log('ShowProfileData' + profiles);
    var member = profiles.values[0];  
    var id = member.id;  
    var firstName = member.firstName;  
    var lastName = member.lastName;  
    var photo = member.pictureUrl;  
    var headline = member.headline;  
    //use information captured above  
    var stringToBind = "<p>First Name: " + firstName + " <p/><p> Last Name: " 
+ lastName + "<p/><p>User ID: " + id + " and Head Line Provided: " + headline 
+ "<p/>"  
    document.getElementById('profiles').innerHTML = stringToBind;  
}  
</script>

<body>
<div id="profiles"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try changing it to your local ip instead.

Comment: No luck Sir @Hackerman

Comment: In your linkedin application, are you using the Live Status as Development, like in this picture https://www.developer.com/imagesvr_ce/1235/LinkedInAPI-Figure01.png

Comment: Hi @Hackerman, I don't see such option in my application settings; checked all available sections. Are you sure such option exists when you create an application now?

Comment: Yep it exists...I created an application on https://developer.linkedin.com in order to check.

Comment: Hi @Hackerman, I verified the settings, the application status is set to 'Development'

Comment: One more point to share with you, I have set website input field as 'http://www.testonly1.com' which doesn't exist as I don't have a website of my own.